# How does a website serve a list of data to the user for page/slider content?

Tags: web, url, networking, server, client

im specifically talking about how when a user goes to a web page with a list of data (articles as an example) does the website send every article (maybe in an array or something) and then the client filters out the data to only visualize the articles for the page that the client is currently viewing? i'm referring to back/next buttons that will display different "pages" of data not different actual web pages (changes in url) or if it doesn't work like that then how does it?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, your question is basically without the URL changing the data in the page changes and how this takes place.

---

So, for this what happens behind the scene is that for every action performed by the user a request is sent and the corresponding data is retrieved and displayed, and this is irrespective of the URL.

---

for example initially,

When the user lands on the page the list of all articles is retrieved and displayed.
Now, if he applies a filter, a request is sent and then data received is displayed.
So as you can see this process is irrespective of changes in the URL.